# iOS App incremental release

Tags: ios

Is it possible to release new version of an ios app in an incremental way from App Store. Say release new version to 10% users and based on feedback we could decide to roll back or push new version to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App store has phased release concept for that.

While your app is in phased release, you can choose to pause the release for a total of 30 days, regardless of the number of pauses. If you remove your app from sale, your current phased release will stop and will not be available for that version again.

For more information, please visit [link](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev3d65fcee1)